# ARDUINO: I can't manage to use a variable as index for my array

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

```
int sum = 3;
int i = 0;
myCode[] = {};
void loop () {
  myCode[i] = sum;
}
```

In this example the variable 'i' gets the value of '3' instead of assigning the value of '3' to the array myCode[] with the index '0' (i).

I honestly don't know why it does this. This is only a small part of the program. I don't include the full program because that would only be confusing for you guys and this is the only part of the program that is not working.

How would I use the value of i to assign a value to the array with i as index??

Comment: yourCode is empty

Comment: If you want to avoid confusing us please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Is `myCode[] = {};` really a valid definition?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you see *undefined behavior*, because `myCode` array does not have enough space. Since you see `myCode[0]` modifying the value of `i` instead of `myCode`, the size of `myCode` in your compiled program is zero, and its address is the same as `i`'s address.

Fixing this problem requires allocating `myCode` at the max size that you expect it to have:

```
int myCode[20] = {0};
```

Now the code is going to work correctly for indexes between 0 and 19, inclusive.

Comment: So I want my array to have max 4 integers so I changed:
    int myCode[] = {};
to:
   int myCode[4] = {};
I'm not sure what the {0} does but my program seems to work so thanks alot.